# How to loop through this json using map function in next.js?

Tags: next.js, strapi

How to loop through this json using map function
[image: json image]

Answer (score 2):

You can loop this json by this ways-

```
import React from 'react';

const index = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {data &&
        data.map((item, i) => (
          <div key={i}>
            // Show all things which you want
          </div>
        ))
      }
    </div>
  );
};
export default index;
```